# Как ввести рандом в telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
   import telebot

   from random import randint


   bot = telebot.TeleBot('5550314934:AAE9r6bVFQcKUv6kjUQT4ojANcMkUugJ_BI')
   @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
   def welcome(message):
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Узнать об обновлениях ---> /updates')

   @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
   def talk(message):
       if message.text=='/updates':
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1. Для выдачи случайного числа от x до у ---> /random')
    elif message.text == 'Ты чмо':
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Сам чмо')
    elif message.text == '/random':
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи x')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, rndm)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не понял, нажми /start')


def rndm(message):
    global answers
    answers = []
    frst_num = message.text
    answers.append(frst_num)
    send2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи у')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send2, rndm2)
def rndm2(message):
    scnd_num = message.text
    answers.append(scnd_num)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, randint(min(answers), max(answers)))



bot.infinity_polling()
```

Как заставить работать команду /random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import telebot

from random import randint


bot = telebot.TeleBot('5550314934:AAE9r6bVFQcKUv6kjUQT4ojANcMkUugJ_BI')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Узнать об обновлениях ---> /updates')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def talk(message):
    if message.text=='/updates':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1. Для выдачи случайного числа от x до у ---> /random')
    elif message.text == 'Ты чмо':
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Сам чмо')
    elif message.text == '/random':
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи x')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, rndm)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не понял, нажми /start')


def rndm(message):
    global answers
    answers = []
    x = int(message.text)
    answers.append(x)
    send2 = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи у')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send2, rndm2)
def rndm2(message):
    y = int(message.text)
    answers.append(y)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Случайное число: {randint(min(answers), max(answers))}')



bot.infinity_polling()
```